repo ubuntu 20.04
Google translated text:
Hello, I have not been able to update the Ubuntu 20.04 repo. I enter the repo http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ through the browser and I access it perfectly, but through the console I enter sudo apt-get update and it shows me the following error: Err: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80(2620:2d:4002:1:1::102) Someone help me, they suggested changing repo and nothing, nor do I have the sources.list configured this way:
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted 
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates  main restricted 
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal  universe 
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

and so on with the security.ubuntu link and the backports link

Original post:
Hola no he podido actualizar el repo de ubuntu 20.04 Entro por el navegador al repo http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ y accedo perfectamente, pero por consola coloco sudo apt-get update y me muestra el siguiente error:
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80(2620:2d:4002:1:1::102)
Alguien me ayude, me sugirieron cambiar de repo y nada tampoco
tengo el sources.list configurado de esta forma:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates  main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal  universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
y asi con el link de security.ubuntu y el de backports

Please ask in English

@ArchismanPanigrahi please see this Meta Q&A Is translating posts using Google Translate acceptable? Please do not translate other people's questions.

@user68186 I didn't know about the policy. Thanks for informing.

@ArchismanPanigrahi You are welcome. :-)

Try:
Edit your sources.list file.
Switch to these repositories:
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

